# Looking For a Specific Illustrated Children's Bible

Tags: bible, resource-request, art, children, books

I'm looking for a very specific illustrated children's Bible that I cannot remember the name of. It has very stylized illustrations (non-realistic bodies, skin colors, etc). I remember this illustrated Bible had stories on one page and full-page illustrations on the other (I don't remember there being both stories and illustrations on the same page together).

One of the more specific illustrations I can remember is the death of Absalom which is drawn from the back (you don't see his face), his fingers are extremely outstretched, his hair is almost in dreads hooked around the tree branch, and his horse (I believe) is shown riding off into the distance. I don't believe this illustration has arrows in his body but I am not 100% sure. Another illustration I remember pretty clearly is the depiction of Elijah raising of the son of the widow of Zarephath. The dead son is colored mostly either grey or blue and Elijah is looking upward with extremely stylized expression of despair. Other illustrations I remember is Satan depicted as a man wearing all black robes during what I think was the Temptation of Christ (with Satan also having either grey or pitch black skin if I recall correctly) and another illustration from an unknown story of a humanoid angel with white skin, a shaved bald head, and white robes.

Overall, this was definitely the most stylized illustrated Bible I ever read as a child and I would absolutely love to find it again. I've asked my parents and they do remember giving it to me and having it on the bookshelf (with clear memories of some of the illustrations frightening me due to their stylistic nature), but they have moved a few times since then and I tried searching for it in their boxes of books and have been unable to find it.

Comment: Can you include some pointers such as some words in the title page (ex: whether it has the word "Bible" in the title), some names (such as illustrator's name), possible publishers, possible years, which denomination church it was used, etc?  Also, approximate number of pages, hard cover vs. soft cover, size.  About the text, which translation was used (NIV, etc.) or is it a free paraphrase for children), whether it includes all the text of the Bible (or just the passages of the stories that are illustrated), whether it is both OT and NT, etc.?

Comment: I do not recall the words in the title page, however I would imagine it includes the word "Bible" in the title page. I do not recall the illustrator's name or publisher. I read it when I was a child, however my dad has been a Lutheran pastor since 1995 so it's most likely from around 1995-2005. I do not remember it being an overly thick book so it would probably be less than 100 pages. I seem to remember that it was a free paraphrase for children and it only included the passages of the stories that are illustrated. It is OT & NT, it includes the story of Absalom and the Temptation of Christ.

Comment: Thanks.  Here's a [search query](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%28children%20bible%29%20AND%20date%3A%5B1990-01-01%20TO%202005-01-01%5D) for archive.org, for those who would like to try.  I'll try to find one too, among these.

Comment: Something else that just came to mind, there is an illustration in this Children's Bible that shows Gandhi holding his hands up while being threatened by many guns pointed at him. I do not remember what verse/passage/story accompanied the Gandhi illustration though. There may have been other illustrations of "modern" items or people however it was definitely closer to the end of the book, as a sort of way to wrap things up.

Comment: Any chance it was *Children of God Storybook Bible* by Desmond Tutu? I don't have a copy, but I remember it had very colorful illustrations in various styles.

Comment: The Biggest Story Bible Storybook by Kevin DeYoung is getting very close as far as art style is concerned, but still isn't it. I'll keep searching but that is the closest I've found so far.